# Delete certain string from comma delimited string C#

Tags: c#, string, csv

I have an some different input strings, e.g

```
string text1 = "Slave 1, Board 3, Point 1, Port 1";
string text2 = "Slave 1, Board 4, Point 1, Port 1";
string text3 = "Slave 1, Board 5, Point 1, Port 1";
string text4 = "Slave 1, Board 6, Point 1, Port 1";
string text5 = "Slave 1, Board 7, Point 4, Port 1";
string text6 = "Slave 1, Board 10, Point 4, Port 1";
```

I need to delete "Board X" value from each string. How can achieve that?

Number after text Board can be different, but names are static.

I write such code, but it seems not working

```
List<String> Items = pointPortPath.Split(',').Select(i => i.Trim()).Where(i => i != string.Empty).ToList(); 

Items.Remove(Items.Where(p=>p.StartsWith("Board")).ToString());
```

Comment: What *can* you do so far? Can you split it into different parts? Find the part you want to remove? Remove it? Set the remaining parts back together? Help us help you and tell us where you are stuck, preferably with the code you already have.

Comment: Board 3 is not permanent value, it can be Board 10. It should be something LIKE % %

Comment: Can you edit your question to be clearer, and provide actual example inputs and outputs then? Note that you are not asking how to delete a "certain" string, because you are asking for wildcard behaviour rather than simply trying to remove a specific value like "Board 3".

Comment: Sorry I was hurried with description, now I changed

Answer (score 3):

You can use Regular expression for this:

```
text1 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(text1 ,@"\b(Board) \d\b","");
```

Comment: It saying "Unrecognised escaped sequence". But I probably fixed it adding @ before.

Comment: Good. @hoozr. Hope you got the solution. If so please mark it as the answer, so it helpts anyone searching for the solution.

Comment: This will leave a empty element in the output (`Slave 1, , Point 1, ...`), which is probably not what the OP intended (on the other hand, the OP did not specify the desired output clearly, so I might be wrong here).

Answer (score 3):

As the saying goes: "If you have one problem, and you try to solve it with Regex, now you have two problems" - therefore, avoiding Regex, here's a solution that might work for you.

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string text1 = "Slave 1, Board 3, Point 1, Port 1";
        string text2 = "Slave 1, Board 4, Point 1, Port 1";
        string text3 = "Slave 1, Board 5, Point 1, Port 1";
        string text4 = "Slave 1, Board 6, Point 1, Port 1";
        string text5 = "Slave 1, Board 7, Point 4, Port 1";
        string text6 = "Slave 1, Board 10, Point 4, Port 1";
        
        Console.WriteLine(DeleteBoardFromString(text1));
        Console.WriteLine(DeleteBoardFromString(text2));
    }
    
    public static string DeleteBoardFromString(string input, bool trimWhitespace = true)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> output = input
            .Split(',')
            .Select(str => trimWhitespace ? str.Trim() : str)
            .Where(str => !str.StartsWith("Board"));

        return string.Join(", ", output);
    }
}
```

**Output**

> Slave 1, Point 1, Port 1
>
> Slave 1, Point 1, Port 1

Comment: This good solution, thanks Matthew! I already achieved by the same.

Comment: Good one, but one should note that your solution will *also* normalize all whitespace around field separators to `, `, i.e., `Point 4    ,     Port 1` will become `Point 4, Port 1`. That's probably a good thing, but side effects should be documented.

Comment: @Heinzi Good spot on the whitespace trimming. I've modified the code to allow trimming as the default behaviour, but with the ability to turn that off. That said, I suspect that `"        Board X"` would no longer work, since it no longer starts with `"Board"` :-(

Comment: If not modifying the whitespace were a requirement, I'd probably trim only for the comparison, i.e. `str.Trim().StartsWith("Board")`. That way, we keep all the original whitespace intact.

Answer (score 1):

try this regular expression for Board followed by any number

```
string target=System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(text1, "Board [0-9]+, ", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Regex

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"Board\s\d+,";
        string substitution = @"";
        string input = @"Slave 1, Board 3, Point 1, Port 1
Slave 1, Board 4, Point 1, Port 1
Slave 1, Board 5, Point 1, Port 1
Slave 1, Board 6, Point 1, Port 1
Slave 1, Board 7, Point 4, Port 1
Slave 1, Board 10, Point 4, Port 1";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
        
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
        string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked with

```
List<String> Items = pointPortPath.Split(',').Select(i => i.Trim()).Where(i => i != string.Empty).ToList(); 

Items.Remove(x=>x.StartsWith("Board"));
```

Thanks all for trying help!